# graphql query to json query

Tags: javascript, json, graphql

Given this GraphQL [example](https://api.entur.org/doc/shamash-journeyplanner/?query=%7B%0A%20%20trip(%0A%20%20%20%20from%3A%20%7Bplace%3A%20%22NSR%3AStopPlace%3A5533%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20to%3A%20%7Bplace%3A%22NSR%3AStopPlace%3A5532%22%7D%0A%20%20)%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20tripPatterns%7Bduration%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%7D), how can I in Javascript do a similar request with JSON?

Using GraphQL the query in the example is:

```
{
  trip(
    from: {place: "NSR:StopPlace:5533" },
    to: {place:"NSR:StopPlace:5532"}
  ) 
    {
    tripPatterns{duration}
  } 
}
```

According to the documentation the URL to query is https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql .

Here is what I tried in Javascript:

```
var url = "https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql";

var tripquery = 
{
    trip: 
    {
        __args: {
            from : {place :"NSR:StopPlace:5533" },
            to : {place :"NSR:StopPlace:5532" }                     
        },
        tripPatterns: {
            duration : true             
        }
    }
};

function jsonQuery(){

    var qry = JSON.stringify(tripquery);
    var url_qry = url + "?query=" + qry;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", url_qry, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log("onreadystatechange");
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200){
            console.log("json-query-OK");
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
        else{
            console.log("xhttp.status      : " + xhttp.status);
            console.log("xhttp.statusText  : " + xhttp.statusText);
            console.log("xhttp.readyState  : " + xhttp.readyState);
            console.log("xhttp.responseType: " + xhttp.responseType);
            console.log("xhttp.responseText: " + xhttp.responseText);
            console.log("xhttp.responseURL : " + xhttp.responseURL);
            console.log("json-not-ok");
        }
    };



    xhttp.send();
    console.log("query sent");
}
```

The code above will result in this output in the console:

```
query sent
api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql?query={%22trip%22:{%22__args%22:{%22from%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5533%22},%22to%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5532%22}},%22tripPatterns%22:{%22duration%22:true}}}:1 POST https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql?query={%22trip%22:{%22__args%22:{%22from%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5533%22},%22to%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5532%22}},%22tripPatterns%22:{%22duration%22:true}}} 400 (Bad Request)
query.js:29 onreadystatechange
query.js:35 xhttp.status      : 400
query.js:36 xhttp.statusText  : Bad Request
query.js:37 xhttp.readyState  : 2
query.js:38 xhttp.responseType: 
query.js:39 xhttp.responseText: 
query.js:40 xhttp.responseURL : https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql?query={%22trip%22:{%22__args%22:{%22from%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5533%22},%22to%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5532%22}},%22tripPatterns%22:{%22duration%22:true}}}
query.js:41 json-not-ok
query.js:29 onreadystatechange
query.js:35 xhttp.status      : 400
query.js:36 xhttp.statusText  : Bad Request
query.js:37 xhttp.readyState  : 3
query.js:38 xhttp.responseType: 
query.js:39 xhttp.responseText: No query found in body
query.js:40 xhttp.responseURL : https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql?query={%22trip%22:{%22__args%22:{%22from%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5533%22},%22to%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5532%22}},%22tripPatterns%22:{%22duration%22:true}}}
query.js:41 json-not-ok
query.js:29 onreadystatechange
query.js:35 xhttp.status      : 400
query.js:36 xhttp.statusText  : Bad Request
query.js:37 xhttp.readyState  : 4
query.js:38 xhttp.responseType: 
query.js:39 xhttp.responseText: No query found in body
query.js:40 xhttp.responseURL : https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql?query={%22trip%22:{%22__args%22:{%22from%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5533%22},%22to%22:{%22place%22:%22NSR:StopPlace:5532%22}},%22tripPatterns%22:{%22duration%22:true}}}
query.js:41 json-not-ok
```

The `__args` in the Json object is something I got from an example online, but I haven't really understood it.

Maybe I'm not sure what exactly to search for, but I can't find some good explanation of how to translate this GraphQL query to a JSON object.

Comment: The best definition of the wire protocol I've seen is [on the graphql.org site](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request).  There is not a standard translation of the GraphQL query syntax into JSON; you pass the query string as a JSON string in a small object wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I did it like this:

```
{
  c_con_tic_PTF(dz: CR, docmanId: 123) {
    docmanId
    dz
    data
  }
}
```

I tried sending this request as curl command in OS X [How to use CURL in OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2017/01/30/curl-post-request-command-line-syntax/):

```
curl \
      -X POST \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --data '{ "query": "{  c_con_tic_PTF(docmanId: 123, dz: CR) { docmanId, dz, data }}" }' \

   *my-graphicQL endpoint url*
```

And I got the response I wanted.

So you want to make something like this from your graphQL query:

```
{ "query": "{  cz_atlascon_etic_PTF(docmanId: 123, dz: CR) { docmanId, dz, data }}" }
```

And now just send request with JS.
If it helps you in any way, this is how my request looked in Java:

```
HttpRequest mainRequest =
HttpRequest.newBuilder()
.uri(URI.create("my graphQL endpoint"))
.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{ \"query\": \"{  c_con_tic_PTF(docmanId: 123, dz: CR) { docmanId, dz, data }}\" }"))
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it in Javascript is using the fetch api. Something like this is how I've done it in the past. You can test it out by copying the code below and then pasting it into Chrome Dev Tools and running it.

```
async function makeGraphQlQuery(urlToResource) {
    const queryObject = {
      query:
        '{ trip( from: {place: "NSR:StopPlace:5533" }, to: {place:"NSR:StopPlace:5532"}) {tripPatterns{duration}} }',
    };
    const response = await fetch(urlToResource, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(queryObject),
    });

    const json = response.json();

    return json;
}

async function sendAsync() { 
  const res = await makeGraphQlQuery('https://api.entur.io/journey-planner/v2/graphql');
  console.log(res); 
}
sendAsync().catch(err => console.log('Error in query', err));
```