# graphql query to json query in graphiql

Tags: graphql

i have a query similar to this i fire in graphiql. this works perfectly and gives me a response
query{
myAccounts(acctKey: "7777888888999") {
ppCode
acctDate
acctLastUpdatedDate
zoneId
}
}

Now for some reason i need to pass the request as a json query instead of graphql query. I came across a solution similar to this [graphql query to json query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502262/graphql-query-to-json-query)

but couldn't quite get how to approach it. Is there any other way to achieve this,

Comment: Hi, please could you [edit] to be clearer what you need, and what you've tried so far? I'm not sure what you mean by "a json query", or why you need it, or what you don't understand about the linked question.

Comment: sure.. by json query i mean something like this {"query":"myAccounts","columns":["ppCode","acctDate"],"AcctKey":["7777888888999"]}. Can i achive something like this and then get the same response. suppose i dont want to handle it through javascript is there a way in graphql to handle this through code

Comment: You can create a POST request, with the same URL and copy this query in the body. Graphql works on top of HTTP, thus this query should succeed.

Comment: just check how graphiQL sends it - check dev tools/network POST request body/details - then recreate it using f.e. js fetch/axios etc.

Comment: @nachiket26 please do not code in comments. u can simply edit your question and show your codes there. you can see here how we can ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To make it as a JSON, change the `myAccounts` return a **String** and then on code make it like `return json_encode($var);`